# Discovering instances of a program on a network

Tags: networking

How would I write a program in such a way that it could discover other instances of itself on the network and let those instances "peer" with each other?

I'm mainly looking for protocols that would allow me to do this (and, hopefully, not put too much stress on the network).

Comment: You'd do it one way with Java, another way with .NET, and you'd probably do it in a totally different way for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a network (=same subnet) you can use [broadcasts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_traffic) to communicate. Although you can't be sure that a broadcast reaches it destination (due to firewall protections against them).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use "Bonjour" protocol, which is itself based on DNS broadcast if i remember well.
While Apple originated, i think specs & base implementation libraries should be available on several OSes/Languages

Comment: "Avahi" is one free implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Send occasional packets using a network broadcast address.